# Adding eggs to lasagna

Tags: lasagna

I have seen this particular part added in recipes for lasagna. What I don't understand is what it means by "add eggs" to cheese. Do I just crack a raw egg and dump it into the cheese mixture? Do I whisk the egg and then mix it with the cheese before layering it on the lasagna? Do I just take a raw egg and just mix it with cheese then layer it?

Comment: By "cheese" do you mean ricotta/cottage cheese? Generally a lasagna recipe has you create a mixture of some sort of soft fresh cheese, fresh herbs like parsley, pepper, maybe nutmeg, along with a raw egg or two. This is one of the many layers of the lasagna.  Some other recipes (usually for Easter) actually contain slices of hard boiled egg. :) Can you clarify?

Comment: @Catija I'm not really too familiar with what cheese to use -- for the longest time I just use shredded mexican cheese for the cheese layer

Comment: I think this is answerable, but it'd be easiest on people (and you'd get fewer questions in comments) if you provided a couple example recipes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of lasagna that I grew up making was a collection of layers of various things. These layers were (at minimum) - sauce; pasta noodles; a mixture of white, soft cheese and other things; and other cheeses, usually mozzarella. This means that there are actually **two** cheese layers - one shredded, the other creamy. Here's a recipe I've grabbed from [Food Network](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/anne-burrell/lasagna-recipe.html) as an example.

One of the steps involves combining the ricotta (some people use cottage cheese instead) with other ingredients including the raw eggs:

> In a small bowl, combine the ricotta, 1/2 the Parmigiano-Reggiano, the eggs, and the basil. Mix to combine well and season with salt.

This mixture is then layered, alternating with the noodles, meat, vegetables, and sauce. The other half of the Parmigiano is sprinkled on top with mozzarella for the cheesy topping and a bite of saltiness. I'm reformatting the quote below to show the different layers more obviously.

> In the bottom of a 9 by 13-inch deep-dish baking dish:
>
> - add a couple ladlefuls of sauce and spread out in an even layer.
> - Arrange a layer of the lasagna noodles to completely cover the sauce.
> - Spread 1/3 of the ricotta mixture over the pasta.
> - Place a layer of pasta going in the other direction as the first layer (this will give a little more stability).
> - Spread a light layer of sauce on the pasta and sprinkle 1/3 of the sausage over the sauce,
> - [Spread a light layer of sauce on the sausage and sprinkle] 1/3 of the mushrooms and zucchini.
> - Sprinkle a layer of mozzarella and some of the remaining Parmigiano-Reggiano over the veggies.
>
> Repeat these layers until all the ingredients have been used up or the pan is full. Be sure that there is a layer of pasta on top covered with sauce and sprinkled with mozzarella and Parmigiano. Cover with foil.

So, to answer your question, yes, the egg is mixed in, raw, with the cheeses to make the cheese layer... but if you're not using a ricotta or cottage cheese and are just using shredded cheese, you probably shouldn't do this.

Comment: No, no.  The eggs go in the noodles.  And no ricotta. Besciamella (béchamel) :  http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/mario-batali/lasagne-bolognese-al-forno-recipe.html .  (and you don't have to worry about chopping up the spinach if you make the pasta in a food processor; reserve the spinach liquid in case you need to add a little back in)

Comment: I should also mention, people who haven't grown up with that style of lasagna tend to think it to be not what they were expecting when they heard 'lasagna'.

Comment: That method doesn't match the description in the question. It's certainly an option but it's not correct for this version.

Comment: There's also the Christmas Eve lasagna (no meat, as it's a fasting day), which is almost all dairy ... but again, eggs are only in the noodles, but there's ricotta in it (sauce is 0.5c butter, 1 large onion diced, 3 large carrots diced; sauté then add 3/4c. flour and cook out the roux; slowly add 7.5c milk cook 'til thickened; add 6c. ricotta, 1.5c. grated parmesan , 1lb cubed fresh mozzarella, 0.75lb cubed fontinella, 1/2t. each of nutmeg, salt and pepper; simmer 'til the cheeses melt together). ... still no egg (except in the noodles)

Comment: Yes, yes, as @Catija notes the eggs go in the cheese mixture, a combo of ricotta, herbs, and grated provolone and mozzarella, as instructed by my Italian men (father, grandfather and great-grandfather).

Answer (score 1):

Beat the eggs slightly and fold into ricotta cheese

Comment: If you mix the eggs and ricotta until it's a uniform mixture, that essentially beats the eggs as part of that process. So while not necessary to get you there, beating them first gets you there a little quicker, IMO. Skip it, and you spend more time mixing the egg-cheese mixture.